# Error:Expected letter.. while running play multi project

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I was trying to run a play sbt multi-project using command 'sbt "project subproject" ~run'
But received following error:

```
 `Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '-'
[error] “
[error] ^
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `sbt "~subproject/run"`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and, it was because I was running sbt . (with a trailing period).

Just using sbt or sbt [command] solved the problem for me